# Логические выражения в Excel

Tags: excel

У меня есть ячейка с формулой B8, она зависит от некоторых данных, и может принимать значение от 0 до 100+, и у меня есть ячейка D8, мне нужно чтобы B8 принимала значение не больше 50, а остаток записывала в ячейку D8. Скажите пожалуйста как этого добиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пользуясь средствами Excel так невозможно сделать (если не брать VB for Excel), поскольку это будет циклическая зависимость: значение ячейки D8 будет зависеть от B8 и на него же и влиять.

Лучше сделайте не так - не трогайте B8, а меняйте скажем C8
То есть в ячейке D8 пишем:

```
=если(B8>50;B8-50;0)
```

А в ячейке C8 пишем

```
=если(B8>50;50;B8)
```

Comment: Конечно с дополнительной ячейкой проще, тем более их полно, но можно извернуться так:

    B8: =ЕСЛИ(ФОРМУЛА()>50;50;ФОРМУЛА())
    D8: =ЕСЛИ(ФОРМУЛА()>50;ФОРМУЛА()-50;0)

Где ФОРМУЛА() - та самая функция, которая изначально вписана в B8...

Comment: попробуйте и увидите что Excel такие вещи не пропускает - будет ругаться на циклические ссылки

Comment: Где цикличность? B8 и D8 результаты выполнения формулы. Подставьте вместо формулы, например, A8*C8.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант:

```
B8=МИН(формула;50)
D8=МАКС(формула-B8;)
```

где *формула* - то, что было раньше в *В8*

Comment: Только что-то тут по-моему нолик забыли

Comment: Спасибо за внимательность, но...  не забыл -опустил. Excel понимает  такую запись.

Answer (score 0):

```
if В8 > 50  
D8 = B8 - 50
B8 = 50
```

Встроенная функция if внутри EXCEL называется ЕСЛИ()